# Datetime conversion one timezone to another timezone in Android

Tags: android

I stuck with timezone conversion can any one help me to get out of it

My code for time conversion is below

```
public static String convertToLocalTimeZone(String date, String timeZone)
{       
    SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a");  
    df1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));  

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
    try {
        calendar.setTime(df1.parse(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  

    SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a");  
    df2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

    return df2.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Parameter timeZone is **America/New_York** and expected is **Asia/Calcutta**

**I'm getting two different string for datetime and time zone now I have to convert datetime according to device local timezone**

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check again

Comment: Check out code at thislink.  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Converttimebetweentimezone.htm

Comment: @Jigar Pandya I have checked that also its not useful for me

Comment: @HarishGodara : then please elaborate what you want? You have to just tweak the code that I provided to convert American time to Asia/Calcutta

Comment: @Jigar Pandya I just wanted to know what I have missed in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Joda-Time and with some modification I have implemented and fixed my issue.

Comment: Posting your solution would be helpful.